# Recently deleted line from a text file as a string left as blank and I cannot remove the blanks from the string

Tags: c

I am reading in from a text file and putting it into a string and then removing a specific line from this string by using a counter to count the number of new lines and then writing to a new string. It works to remove the specific line I want but it leaves blanks in its place when I write it back to the text file. Im trying to remove these blanks but struggling to find a solution.

Ive tried searching through the string manually to remove the spaces by using a for loop and searching for ' ' but it returned unidentified symbols I was unsure about.

```
void removeBook(int line){
  char *bookrecord = "records/bookrecord.csv";
  FILE *file = fopen(bookrecord,"r");
  int currentline = 1;
  int count = 0,newcount = 0,length;
  char *string;
  char *newstring;

  fseek(file,0,SEEK_END);
  length = ftell(file);
  fseek(file,0,SEEK_SET);
  string = malloc(length+1);
  fread(string,sizeof(char),length,file);
  fclose(file);
  string[length] = '\0';

  length = strlen(string);
  newstring = malloc(length+1);

  while(string[count] != '\0')
  {
    if(currentline == line)
    {
      while(string[count] != '\n')
      {
        count++;
      }
    }
    if(string[count] == '\n')
    {
      currentline++;
    }
    printf("%c",string[count]);
    newstring[newcount] = string[count];
    count++;
    newcount++;
  }
}

void main(){
  removeBook(2);
}
```

[Input from Text File/Output String](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x945s.png)

Comment: `printf("%c",string[count]);` is done unconditional to whether you read a newline or not. You want to skip both the line content *and* the newline at the end. You're doing the former; not the latter. Unrelated, heaven help you if your file doesn't end with a final newline; that `while(string[count] != '\n')` will be a killer in that case.

Comment: A less convoluted way to do this would be to find where the line begins and where it ends and then `memcpy` fileBegin to lineBegin and lineEnd to fileEnd to a new char array. The resulting length is fileEnd - (lineEnd - lineBegin).